# How to remap keyboard keys in grub bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I am using Windows and Ubuntu by Dual Boot. Whenever I start my laptop, I need to select any one OS.
But the problem is, Enter key is broken in my laptop. So I cannot select an OS.

Is there any way to remap a working key to Enter key so that I can use that working key as Enter key?

(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remap any keys if you just want to select another OS in GRUB. Simply press the right arrow key after selecting the OS you want to boot.